# Calculate a percentage of column by userid (SQL)

Tags: sql

I have this really small table where I need to calculate
**what percent of users used a time-off feature?**
time_off_used parameters show if users used that feature  (1),  or not (0)

| role | user_id | time_off_used |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Admin | 45ds4f5d4sfd5s5fd5s4dfg | 0 |
| Admin | 45ds5f4ds5sdf45dfs5sdgfgf | 1 |
| Regular | 45ds4f5d4sfd5s5fd5s4dfg | 0 |
| Admin | dh454hkd564khdg564kd6fgjg | 1 |
| Project manager | sgj3js32jgfsj1s2jss1jgssg54 | 1 |
| Admin | 45ds5f4ds5sdf45dfs5sdgfgf | 1 |
| Regular | 45d34frty5d4sfd5s5fd5s4dfg | 0 |
| Admin | dhy556gd564khdg564kd6fgjg | 1 |
| Project manager | sgj3js32jgfsj1s2jss1jgssg54 | 1 |

I need just one number as a result, for example 70.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple as this :

```
select sum(time_off_used)* 100.0 / count(*) as percentage_used_feature
from tablename
```

Comment: Hmm, something seems off, cause if the user used the feature it gives a percentage 100 right next to it, and if it didn't 0 and I need to calculate the percentage of users that used the feature that means where time_off_used = 1, but i dont know how to form it.

Comment: @AleksandraMilicevic I think you want the second query , if not your question is not clear , edit your question and add the expected result for your  sample data and explain one example in plain english

Comment: Lets say, this is just an example, the percentage of users(people) that used the feature is 70, I need just one number as a result, is there any way to get it?